# Задача с областью видимости JS

Tags: javascript

```
function t(){
}


let counter = t;

console.log(counter()); //1
console.log(counter()); //2
console.log(counter()); //3
console.log(counter()); //4
console.log(counter()); //5
```

Задача: Описать финкцию t , что бы при каждом вызове console.log() выводилось соответствующее значение после коментария. Для первого вызова - 1 , для 5ого -  5. Без использования глобальных переменных!! Весь код должен лежать в функции.

Мне кажется, всё дело в области видимости. Но я в этом не уверен и не знаю с чего мне начать. Укажите пожалуйста направление для мыслей! Спасибо

Comment: почитайте про замыкание

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/            - читать все.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что 1. _`let counter = t;`_ - должно быть не `t`, а `t()`. 2. _"Весь код должен лежать в функции"_ - не совсем верное утверждение. Впрочем, можно выполнить и строго по условию, но, вероятно, получится немного не то, что хотят увидеть. UPDATE: при исправлении первого пункта второй теряет актуальность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой пример замыкания. И да, вместо t, должно быть t() по логике условия.

```js
function t() {
  var i = 0;
  return function() {
    return ++i;
  }; 
}

var counter = t();

console.log(counter()); //1 
console.log(counter()); //2 
console.log(counter()); //3 
console.log(counter()); //4 
console.log(counter()); //5
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это то  что было нужно!

Answer (score 3):

Ну раз уж [ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709207/178988) с тем, что нужно, запостили, запощу и ответ с тем, что НЕ нужно, зато полностью соответствует условию из вопроса:

```js
function t() {
  var x = 1;
  counter = () => ++x;
  return x;
}

let counter = t;

console.log(counter()); //1
console.log(counter()); //2
console.log(counter()); //3
console.log(counter()); //4
console.log(counter()); //5
```

Comment: Пояснения бы помогли, а так неплохо!

Answer (score 3):

Справедливости ради, стоит заметить что задачу можно решить и одной функцией.

```js
function t() {
   if (typeof t._counter !== 'number') {
      t._counter = 0
   }

   return ++t._counter
}

const counter = t

console.log(counter())  // 1
console.log(counter())  // 2
console.log(counter())  // 3
console.log(counter())  // 4
console.log(counter())  // 5
```

Comment: Эм.. Код в ответе ничего общего не имеет с named function expression. Чтобы было named function expression, надо `var t = function t() {`

Comment: @Qwertiy А по-моему имеет самое непосредственное. Посмотрите на переменную `counter`. По-условию, ей присваивается функция, а не вызов. А согласно условию, место для для хранения переменных между вызовами остаётся только в объекте функции, к которому можно обратиться как раз по имени.

Comment: `t` объявлена через function declaration, а не function expression и само имя `t` принадлежит внешнему скоупу, а не замыканию функции. Проверяется легко: после `const counter = t` можно добавить `t = null` и этот код упадёт. А вот если объявить `t` как `var t = function t() {`, то `var t` принадлежит внешнему скоупу, а `function t` - внутреннему (то самое named function expression), что обеспечит работоспособность кода при присваивании `t = null` снаружи. Собственно для этого оно и нужно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Однако в задаче нет таких ограничений как `t = null`. Так что всё норм.  А вот ссылку я может и очень хорошую подобрал. Суть же в том, что к функции по имени можно обратиться из неё самой.

Comment: Да, с решением всё нормально - условию оно соответствует. Я только про неправильное пояснение говорил.

Answer (score 0):

Варианта с генератором еще нету?

```js
const g = (function* (i){
    while(true) yield i++;
})(1);

function t(){
    return g.next().value;
}

let counter = t;

console.log(counter()); //1
console.log(counter()); //2
console.log(counter()); //3
console.log(counter()); //4
console.log(counter()); //5
```

Comment: Но ведь g - глобальная переменная...

Comment: @Qwertiy можно как в соседнем ответе, запихнуть в t)